# Calling ToString with a nominated format returns Char rather than String

Tags: string, vb.net, formatting

I am making a generic method to print an array to a delimited string, and the ToString() method is behaving strangely. Take this function:

```
Public Function ToString(Of T)(array() As T, delimiter As String, format As String) As String
    Dim resultBuilder As New StringBuilder

    If array IsNot Nothing AndAlso array.Count > 0 Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To array.Count - 1
            If i Then resultBuilder.Append(delimiter)

            resultBuilder.Append(array(i).ToString(format))
        Next
    End If
    Return resultBuilder.ToString
End Function
```

and present it with

```
Dim a() As Integer = {32, 14, 7, 0}

Label1.Text = ToString(a, ", ", "0000")
```

I would expect the function to return

```
0032, 0014, 0007, 0000
```

instead the function is returning

```
3, 1, 7, 0
```

I assume the problem is the ToString() function is struggling to know what type it is being applied to, but the debugger is keenly aware that `T` is `Integer` and knows otherwise how to correctly format an integer in the Watch. No matter the type, the behaviour is still unusual. What on earth is going on?

Comment: It appears you have Option Strict set to OFF, which is not good (and also misleading here) -- You could use the `AppendFormat()` method of your StringBuilder, e.g. `resultBuilder.AppendFormat(format, array(i))`, passing `(a, ", ", "{0:0000}")` to the method <- which should not be named `ToString()`, maybe `ToDelimitedString()`. Unless you want to override the default `ToString()` method

Comment: BTW, is `If i Then [...]` a typo? Shouldn't it be `If i > 0 Then [...]`?

Comment: Note that Jimi's second comment about the probably-wrong `If` statement is something that the compiler would have flagged if you had `Option Strict On`.

Comment: The `if i` clause is actually shorthand for i > 0, as if i is zero it is identically the same as a false boolean,  and any other value will be interpreted as true, which was as I used it. I have never actually come across where Option Strict is even set, so have not ever explicitly controlled it.